# Flexbox: variable stretching with "justify-content: stretch"

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a `row` directed flex container (row) that contains n `row` directed flex containers (cells) containing a fixed size div (thumbnail) and a `column` directed nested flex container.

When not wrapped, it is displayed as I expect, with the thumbnail in the top-left, and the nested container to its right, stretched to fit the parent height.

However, when the cells wrap their contents, if the contents are not large enough to fit the parent, the nested container is only stretched to fit half the height of the cell.

I'd like it to be adjacent to the fixed size element that is now above it.

This is a bit hard to explain, but hopefully the pictures below make it clearer.

Not wrapped:

[image: Not wrapped]

In the below picture, my desired result is that the red and yellow  boxes in the left cell would be adjacent, and the orange box adjacent to the bottom of the cell.

Wrapped:

[image: Wrapped]

```css
div.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: no-wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  background: purple;
}

div.cell {
  margin: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: stretch;
  padding: 5;
  background: green;
  flex-basis: 0;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

div.thumb {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
  background: red;
}

div.right {
  display: flex;
  align-self: stretch;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 200px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background: blue;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-basis: 0;
}

div.headline {
  background: yellow;
}

div.sub {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut accumsan ipsum et pulvinar laoreet.</div>
      <div class="sub">Test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <div class="thumb"></div>
    <div class="right">
      <div class="headline">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut accumsan ipsum et pulvinar laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut accumsan ipsum et pulvinar laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        Ut accumsan ipsum et pulvinar laoreet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut accumsan ipsum et pulvinar laoreet</div>
      <div class="sub">Test</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://codepen.io/fjolnir/pen/QvjKez

Comment: Have you tried `align-content: flex-start` on `div.cell`? http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mmeQXN?editors=1100

Comment: For the "Test" footer to be pinned to the bottom you will have to switch the container to `flex-direction: column` or use absolute positioning.